# Is there a better way to chain the String#replace method?

Tags: javascript, string

I understand that regex is a possibility, but I'd like to edit a lot of things at once. Minimalizing chaining. It just doesn't look to great in code.

for example,
Let's say the alphabet is jumbled up.
A would be E
B would be H
E would be D

How would I change ABE into EHD using a minimal amount of functions?
To be crystal clear, I have an object with this jumbled up alphabet.

TL;DR:

Best way to bulk-update letters in a string to their assigned counterparts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write some logic where you would split the string into an array of characters and then compare the separate values using `map()` and replace when needed. Then join the array back to a string.

```js
const original = "ABE";
const splitted = original.split("");

const replaced = splitted.map((letter) => {
  if(letter === "A") return "E"
  if(letter === "B") return "H"
  if(letter === "E") return "D"
  return letter
});

console.log(replaced.join(""));
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return letter` as the default

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use a regular expression but also pair it with a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```js
const substitutions = {
  "A": "E",
  "B": "H",
  "E": "D"
};

function transform(input) {
  return input.replace(/./g, char => {
    const sub = substitutions[char] ?? char;
    
    return sub;
  });
}

console.log(transform("HELLO WORLD!"));
console.log(transform("BEAUTIFUL!"));
console.log(transform("BOATS ARE EXCELLENT "));
```

The regex `/./g` simply matches every single character and the replacer function then checks if it exists in `substitutions` and returns that. Or if it doesn't exist, it falls back to the same character thanks to the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

This requires you to specify lowercase and uppercase characters explicitly in `substitutions`.

```js
const substitutions = {
  "a": "e",
  "A": "E",
  "b": "h",
  "B": "H",
  "e": "d",
  "E": "D"
};

function transform(input) {
  return input.replace(/./g, char => {
    const sub = substitutions[char] ?? char;
    
    return sub;
  });
}

console.log(transform("Hello world!"));
console.log(transform("Beautiful!"));
console.log(transform("Boats Are Excellent "));
```

If you always want the replacement to match the case (`a -> e` and `A -> E`) and do not want the extra entries in `substitutions`, then  you can can check the case of the character and transform the replacement:

```js
const substitutions = {
  "A": "E",
  "B": "H",
  "E": "D"
};

function transform(input) {
  return input.replace(/./g, char => {
    const upperChar = char.toLocaleUpperCase();
    
    if (!(upperChar in substitutions))
      return char;
      
    const isUpper = char === upperChar;
    const sub = substitutions[upperChar];

    if (isUpper) 
      return sub.toLocaleUpperCase();

    return sub.toLocaleLowerCase();    
  });
}

console.log(transform("Hello world!"));
console.log(transform("Beautiful!"));
console.log(transform("Boats Are Excellent "));
```